# Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.util.List]

Tags: spring

I have a spring xml file like this named "**request-details-upload.xml**"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    ">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/jobs/environment.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/jobs/clients.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/jobs/edx/request-details.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/jobs/dynamoDbClients.xml" />

 <bean id="requestDetailsFetchAndDecryptDataDao" class="com.amazon.edx.dao.FetchAndDecryptDataDaoDynamoDbImpl"
 c:dataUploadDao-ref="requestDetailsDataUploadDao"
 c:dataTransformer-ref="requestDetailsDataTransformer" 
 />
 <util:list id="requestDetailsKeyItemAttributesMetadata" value-type="com.amazon.edx.manager.ItemAttributesMetaData">
        <ref bean="RequestId"/>
        <ref bean="RequestDate"/>
 </util:list>

 <util:list id="requestDetailsNonKeyItemAttributesMetadata" value-type="com.amazon.edx.manager.ItemAttributesMetaData">        
        <ref bean="CreatedBy"/>
        <ref bean="UpdatedTime"/>           
</util:list>

 <bean id="RequestId" class="com.amazon.edx.manager.ItemAttributesMetaData" 
    c:itemAttributeName="RequestId"
/> 

   <bean id="RequestDate" class="com.amazon.edx.manager.ItemAttributesMetaData" 
    c:itemAttributeName="RequestDate"
/> 

<bean id="CreatedBy" class="com.amazon.edx.manager.ItemAttributesMetaData" 
    c:itemAttributeName="CreatedBy"
/> 
 <bean id="UpdatedTime" class="com.amazon.edx.manager.ItemAttributesMetaData" 
    c:itemAttributeName="UpdatedTime"
/> 

    <!-- upload manager -->
  <bean id = "requestDetailsDataUploadManager" class ="com.amazon.edx.manager.DataUploadManagerImpl" 
c:fetchAndDecryptDataDao-ref="requestDetailsFetchAndDecryptDataDao"
c:keyAttributes-ref="requestDetailsKeyItemAttributesMetadata"
c:nonKeyAttributes-ref="requestDetailsNonKeyItemAttributesMetadata"
/>

 <bean id = "requestDetailsUploadToEdx" class = "com.amazon.edx.UploadDataToEdx"
c:dataUploadManager-ref ="requestDetailsDataUploadManager"
/>
</beans>
```

and another xml named **request-details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    ">

  <bean id="requestDetailsDataUploadDao" class="com.amazon.edx.dao.DataUploadClientImpl"
 c:someName="xxxxxxxxxx"
 c:otherName="yyyyyyyyy"    
    />

  <util:list id="requestDetailsColumnMetaData" value-type="com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData">
        <ref bean="RequestId"/>
        <ref bean="RequestDate"/>
        <ref bean="CreatedBy"/>
        <ref bean="UpdatedTime"/>            
 </util:list>

  <bean id="RequestId" class="com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData"
    c:attributeName="RequestId"
    c:dataType="VARCHAR2"
    c:columnDisplayName="REQUEST_ID"
   /> 

   <bean id="RequestDate" class="com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData"
    c:attributeName="RequestDate"
    c:dataType="VARCHAR2"
    c:columnDisplayName="REQUEST_DATE"
    />  


   <bean id="CreatedBy" class="com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData"
    c:attributeName="CreatedBy"
    c:dataType="VARCHAR2"
    c:columnDisplayName="CREATED_BY"
    />  
    <bean id="UpdatedTime" class="com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData"
    c:attributeName="UpdatedTime"
    c:dataType="NUMBER"
    c:columnDisplayName="UPDATED_TIME"
    />  

   <bean id="requestDetailsDataTransformer" class="com.amazon.edx.transformer.DataTransformerImpl"
   c:dataFlattener-ref="requestDetailsDataFlattener"
   c:columnMetadata-ref="requestDetailsColumnMetaData"
    c:delimiter="{tabDelimiter}"
     />

   <util:constant id="tabDelimiter"
        static-field="com.amazon.edx.transformer.Delimiters.TAB_DELIMITER"    />

    <bean id="requestDetailsDataFlattener"   class="com.amazon.edx.flattener.JsonDataFlattenerImpl" 
      c:multipleRowColumnName=""
     />
  </beans>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestDetailsDataTransformer' defined in class path resource [META-INF/jobs/edx/request-details.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.util.List]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.util.List]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.amazon.edx.manager.ItemAttributesMetaData] to required type [com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

It says cannot convert from `java.util.ArrayList` to `java.util.List`. I am not even using `java.util.ArrayList`. I am new to Spring and not able to understand the exact cause of this error.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ahh...figured out the issue. There is a conflict in the bean ids present in the lists in both the files. Bean id's should be unique even if they are in different .xml files. There would be a conflict when we import one file into other.

Answer (score 0):

If you use List type dependency, since it is a interface, spring container create an object of its implementation class ArrayList.

For Set type dependency, spring container creates an object of its implementation class LinkedHashSet.

For Map type dependency, spring container creates an object of its implementation class LinkedHashMap.

For Properties type dependency, since it is a class, spring container creates an object of class Properties only.

Comment: Is this a question or ans answer?

Comment: Answer for this question->

It says cannot convert from java.util.ArrayList to java.util.List. I am not even using java.util.ArrayList. I am new to Spring and not able to understand the exact cause of this error.

Comment: Got it. I'm gonna suggest an edit to make it more clear that you're answering a question